# Solving a differential equation with a changing boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In the book, *The Mathematics of Diffusion*, pp 33 and 34, the solution of the diffusion equation

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$$

for the boundary condition of $C_{x=0}=kt$ (k is avconstant) is given to be
$$C = kt\Bigg[\Bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{2Dt}\Bigg)erfc\frac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi Dt}}exp\big(\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\big)\Bigg]$$
and for $C_{x=0}=kt^{1/2}$, the solution is
$$C=kt^{1/2}\Bigg[exp\big(\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\big)-\frac{x\pi^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{Dt}}erfc\frac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\Bigg]$$

How these two different equations are derived depending on the C function?

Comment: They come from searching for similarity solutions to the heat equation. See [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M546/SimSol1.pdf) for more information.